# Plugin RegisterUrlRulesEvent - Regex URL-Routing gives 404

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugins, routing, migration

I'm updating a Craft 2 plugin to Craft 3 and I'm having difficulties getting the Regex URLs working correctly. The eocs I'm using: [Craft3 Docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#plugin-hooks) 
I used `pluginfactory.io` to create the basic craft3 plugin scaffold.

 For context: the plugin name is `expedweather`.

This is the Route I'm trying to register:

```php
$map_page = 'data/<range:\w+>/<peak:\w+>/<view:\w+>/<parameter:\w+>';
$event->rules[$map_page] = 'expedweather/forecastPanel';
```

In my DefaultController.php I've got this:

```php
protected $allowAnonymous = ['index', 'forecast-panel'];
```

And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but All I get is

> HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException Page not found. ↵
>   Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException

**I've made sure the plugin is enabled in the backstage.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** I was able to solve *half of* my Problem:

Seems the Regex didn't like the "pure" slashes `/` in the URL between the parameters, once I escaped those, through backslashes like this: `\/` it no longer gave me a `yii\base\InvalidRouteException`.

The new Problem I have now is that it can't find the action I'm referring to, see below:

```php
// Path of File: ./src/Expedweather.php; in EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES

$map_page = 'data\/<range:\w+>\/<peak:\w+>\/<view:\w+>\/<parameter:\w+>';
$event->rules[$map_page] = 'expedweather/forecast-panel';

// Exert from ./src/controllers/DefaultController:
protected $allowAnonymous = ['index', 'forecast-panel'];
...
public function actionForecastPanel() {...}
```

An additional piece of info: I'm able to route to the DefaultController's index Function by removing `/forecast-panel` from the target action.